# xbindkeys on one keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, keyboard, xkb, xbindkeys

I have the current setup:

- One PS2 Keyboard
- One USB Keyboard

Then I use this:

```
xinput --create-master SecondKeyboard

xinput --reattach "Keyboard Id" "Master Id"
```

to separate them.

I thought I could just create a custom layout and voilá, one keyboard for writing and another for shortcuts, then I discovered xkb doesn't allow to create layouts that click multiples keys (as in pressing <kbd>capslock</kbd> and it doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>).

So my thought was, have xbindkeys only run on one of the keyboards, since they have different id's. Can I make this happen?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, however you could make XKB send a keysym on one keyboard that doesn't exist in the other layout, and make xbindkeys react to that keysym.

Comment: @Gilles how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Quick summary of the various levels involved:

Your keyboard generates scan codes. These are mapped by the kernel input layers to keycode events on `/dev/input/eventX`. The X `evdev` driver takes these events, and translates them to keysyms. Then XInput extension makes all events from slaves of the Virtual core keyboard available as normal X events, while the other events are only available as XInput events.

So you have the following options:

1) Set up a custom scancode to keycode mapping. These mappings are per device, so this is actually possible, but this is done via an IOCTL, and there seem to be no ready-made tools for it other than the [hwdb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) in `udev`. You can then use the new keycides in `xkb`. Both keyboards are kept as core keyboards.

2) Extend `xbindkeys` to understand XInput events, so you can use it to bind on events from a non-core keyboard. This will need programming, but should be comparatively straightforward. In this case, decouple one keyboard from the core keyboard as you have already done.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help I'm having a bit of a struggle though, since the PS2 isnt showing up in the Virtual Core keyboard @dirkt